# Explode cell directly at function output

Tags: matlab

I'm currently writing a module to write HTML content for my MATLAB project.
To keep flexibility, I wrote my code like this :

```
function content = get_content(obj, elements)
    % Return the HTML of the page
    body_content = obj.get_body(elements);
    header_content = obj.get_header();
    content = {
        header_content{:} ...
        body_content{:} ...
        '</html>' ...
    };
end
function content = get_header(obj, elements)
    content = {
        '<!DOCTYPE html>' ...
        '<html lang="en">' ...
        '<head>' ...
        '    <meta charset="utf-8" />' ...
        '    <title>Report</title>' ...
        '    ' ...
        '    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">' ...
        '    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>' ...
        '    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>' ...
        '    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>' ...
        '    ' ...
            obj.css{:} ...
        '</head>' ...
    }
end
% ....
```

So, my issue appears when I try to concat the content returned by another function
Currently I have to do this :

```
function content = get_content(obj, elements)
    % Return the HTML of the page
    body_content = obj.get_body(elements);
    header_content = obj.get_header();
    content = {
        header_content{:} ...
        body_content{:} ...
        '</html>' ...
    };
end
```

But, I would like to have everything on the same line, like this :

```
function content = get_content(obj, elements)
    % Return the HTML of the page
    content = {
        obj.get_header(){:} ...
        obj.get_body(elements){:} ...
        '</html>' ...
    };
end
```

Obviously, when I do this, I have the following error :

```
    ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.
```

Do you have a simple way/hack to do something like this ?

Regards